# About the meaning of "./a" in gcc

Tags: gcc, output, .a

When I run

```
$ gcc hello.c
$ ./a
Hello, World.
```

I don't know what `./a` exactly indicates.

What is it? What does it stand for?

If you know the meaning of it, I'd really appreciate that you would share.

Answer (score 2):

`./` is the current directory when using a Unix-like shell (like bash.) The name of the executable GCC produces is `a.exe`.

So to run the produced executable, you need to specify the path to to it, in this case "the current directory", which is `./`, and the name of the executable, which is `a.exe`. Since you can omit the `.exe` when running executables on Windows, instead of `./a.exe` you can just run it with `./a`.

If you were to use the Windows command-line shell (like cmd.exe or PowerShell) you would instead just type `a`, because the current directory (`.\` in this case, Windows uses `\` instead of `/` for the directory separator character) is searched for executables by default. Unix shells do not, which is why you need `./`.

If you want to give the produced executable a different name, for example `hello.exe`, you can:

```sh
gcc hello.c -o hello.exe
```

You would then run that with:

```sh
./hello
```

or:

```sh
./hello.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

.a is the standard/default output of the compiled program, when no output name is provided.

When you've compiled **C** program and given no name to the output file, gcc will automatically set the output file name as **a**.

The file name is overwritten for the last compiled **C** program, when no output name is provided.

This standard is same in both Unix and Windows.

To set name for the output program, Use `-o` argument followed by the  output name `sum_program`

`gcc sum_program.c -o sum_program`

Depending on the library use, and other linkers, additional arguments like `-o`  can be added for compilation.